# Unable to install ZMQ on xampp based Apache Server (windows 10)

Tags: php, websocket, zeromq, ratchet

I am trying to install ZMQ on XAMPP based Apache server. (working on windows 10)
Following is the list I have already done in order to install ZMQ

1. Copied `libzmq.dell` into xampp/php
2. Copied `php_zmq.dll` into xampp/php/ext
3. Included both xampp/php and xampp/php/ext in environment variable

But keeps on getting the following error.

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_zmq.dll' - The specified module could not be found.  in Unknown on line 0
```

What could be the possible reason. According to warning, it says it did not found php_zmq.dll but is there.

what could be the possible reason

Comment: Did you include php into your system it's path variables?
Something like C:\xampp\bin\php\php5.6.15

Comment: I hope you added libzmq.dll and not libzmq.dell

Answer (score 1):

I am using Wamp, but the suggestion in comment from mitchken worked for me.

> Did you include php into your system it's path variables? Something like C:\xampp\bin\php\php5.6.15 – mitchken Mar 10 at 11:52